# Design changes in vb6 takes longer time for checkin in TFS

Tags: tfs, vb6

I am facing 2 problems during checkin of design changes in TFS 2012.

1. When I made the some design changes (for example alignment of buttons), codes in frm file gets rearranged. Which gives me a lot of differences even though there are very few (If I manually cut and paste the code in proper place then I can see only few lines of mismatching)
2. If there are some unwanted changes in frm files then there will be changes in respective frx files also. My question if I undo (delete the unwanted changes in TFS ) then how can I differentiate between required and unwanted changes of frx files ?

These two things are killing my lot of time. Please help me to solve these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Its not always the case, but usually the amount of churn in generated files like the frm file is caused by people by selectively checkin parts of that file. By selectively checking in parts of a generated file it causes visual studio to make more drastic changes to the file than one would expect beforehand. If you checkin the complete file a few times this behavior should go away. If it still persists, another option would be to swap the merge tooling to something that suits you better https://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/. E.g. winmerge can be modified to ignore moved sections if they are not modified.

Comment: My case is different from your example. I will give an example, before changing the code's 1st and 2nd lines were 'A' and 'B', after making changes in code the code will automatically rearrange with first line as 'B' and second line as 'A'. So now I problem is file content is same but compare will show differences due mismatch in line.

Answer (score 1):

Every VB6 project in source control faces this issue. I find it useful to break up my work into many smaller changes, and diff and/or check-in changes only in those smaller chunks. This usually makes it much clearer what actually changed.